# What to do with this non-normally distributed and near-categorical data?

Tags: regression, normality-assumption

I have a dependent variable (monetary transfers made by 'dictators' in an experimental dictator game) that is non-normally distributed, and which also appears to be multi-modal (it was collected as a continuous variable).

I would greatly appreciate advice on how best to approach this data, especially when it comes to regressions. The main IV is an experimenter-determined amount ('wage'). I have estimated Tobit models, median regressions, and have also separated out the 'participation decision' (does dictator make a positive transfer?) from the 'contribution decision' (if the dictator contributed a positive amount, then how much?) and modeled these separately using logit and OLS. I have also estimated a cubic model which works very well.

But this all feels rather ad-hoc, and I'm sure there must be a more appropriate approach for dealing with this kind of data. Can anyone advise on this?

Many thanks in advance!
Tanya

[image: Histogram of transfers made by dictators to recipients]

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without us knowing what the objectives are of your analysis.  Could you elaborate on these?

Comment: I gather you want to see if `transfer` is a function of experimenter manipulated `wage`. How was `wage` manipulated? Are there fixed levels (eg, `high wage` vs `low wage`), if so, how many levels? Etc.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. 'Wage' has 6 levels: 0, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 and $1. The objective is to identify whether 'transfer' is a function of 'wage' (as acknowledged by Gung).

Comment: Perhaps you may want to ask two questions: was making of any transfer related to wage and, if so, was the amount of transfer related to wage among those who made a transfer.

Comment: Hi Joel,Thanks for your comment. I did do this - as noted in the original question - and this is one way of looking at the data. What I am really interested in is - is there a regression model - or indeed, a transformation (of the DV) - that deals with this simultaneous issue of non-normality and multi-modality? I am sure this kind of data appears in other disciplines, but I can't find it! Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is more plots. Maybe you've already done this. Certainly a scatter plot of the two variables (probably with some jitter to avoid overplotting). Maybe add a smooth curve (such as loess) to that plot. Given that wage takes only six values, you might also do a parallel box plot.

One possible method is quantile regression. This deals with the multimodality by regressing on the quantiles rather than the mean. You can choose your quantiles. I would suggest at least 3 quantiles, as you seem to have three modes (at least in a vague sense).

Given that it looks like there were a lot of cases of 0 transfer, another possibility is a two stage regression; there are various forms of this, but, basically, the first stage looks at any vs. none, the second stage looks at "some".